# Duplicating a git repo into another organization

Tags: git, repository, code-duplication

Git newbie question. I have two organizations setup, and would like to duplicate/copy a repository from one organizations into another. 
What would be the steps for that ?

Comment: Is this a one-time copy operation or should the two repositories be kept up to date continuously?

Comment: I really think the first step is to [read the docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Consider `testRepo` is repo name under some org or user `sampleOrg`

so your git url will be `https://github.rackspace.com/sampleOrg/testRepo`

step 1. create repo with same name under other org, where u need to duplicate.

```
   eg: `https://github.rackspace.com/sampleOrgMirror/testRepo`
```

step 2. run: `git clone --bare https://github.com/sampleOrg/testRepo.git`

step 3: run: `cd testRepo.git`

step 4: run: `git push --mirror https://github.com/sampleOrgMirror/testRepo.git`

step 5: run: `cd ..`

step 6: run: `rm -rf testRepo.git`

now your code available in `https://github.com/sampleOrgMirror/testRepo.git`

you can follow link for more details
https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/duplicating-a-repository

Comment: will this keep other information like commits and branchs ?

Comment: is step 6 necessary in this process, or is it optional? what does `-rf` do?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with [git-copy](https://github.com/cybertk/git-copy).

```
git copy https://github.com/org1/repo.git https://github.com/org2/repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply clone the repository via [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

```
git clone path/to/other/organizations/repository
```

Comment: This puts the repo on your local machine; it doesn't copy it to a new remote.

Comment: @nasch “to a remote” was not asked, and is unspecific too. It depends on your target and target state. Use `clone --bare` if you want to clone into a bare repository.

Comment: " I have two organizations setup, and would like to duplicate/copy a repository from one organizations into another."  Unless the "other organization" is somehow on the local machine, I don't see how this can answer the question.

Comment: Going back to your initial comment, I assume you mean clone pulls the data to where the command is being run? If you connect to the remote server you can run commands on the server. Running commands on a remote system is standard administrative practice.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your answer to include that step.

Comment: That's specific to your environment though. Not generally applicable or to OP question - which does not describe the environment.

Comment: Running commands on a local machine is specific to my environment?

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer to add what you feel is missing.

Comment: I think the comments are sufficient.